# xamarin forms IOS map opens in wrong location

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps

I'm developing an app in xamarin forms supposed to works on android and ios.
The problem is that IOS maps displays a wrong location.

### IOS Location (WRONG)

[image: IOS Location (WRONG)]

### Android Location (RIGHT)

[image: Android Location (RIGHT)]

Code:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://maps.apple.com/?ll={0}", x + ',' + y));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(uri);
                Device.OpenUri(uri);
            break;

            case Device.Android:
                uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + x + ',' + y);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(uri);
                Device.OpenUri(uri);
            break;

        }
```

In this example `x="39.7301803"` and `y="-8.8438668"`

### UPDATE

Replacing the code above with `ExternalMaps` plugin

```
var success = CrossExternalMaps.Current.NavigateTo(Store.Name, Double.Parse(x), Double.Parse(y));
```

Exactly the same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your links (manually put together) open in the right app and point to the same location

- [Google-maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=39.7301803,-8.8438668)
- [Apple-maps](http://maps.apple.com/?ll=39.7301803,-8.8438668)

But when I set the y param to "0" I end up in the exact area of your wrong screenshot. Could it be that there is a problem in your code? Like y not being set (prior to the snippet)

Could you share more of your code?

The difference between both platforms is how you build the string. I would suggest to change the iOS part to:

```
uri = new Uri("http://maps.apple.com/?ll="+ x + ',' + y));
```

Comment: I already replaced x and y to correct values and the result is the same

Comment: In this example `x="39.7301803"` and `y="-8.8438668"`

Comment: could it be that i need to convert the coordinates to another format to use apple map?

Comment: For example I wanted to make sure if the variables are strings or doubles. And if this is different between the platforms.
If they are doubles, you should maybe check how the doubles are serialized: from the coordinates I suspect that the current culture is likely to be Portuguese, with that the decimal separator would be "," instead of "." (as expected by maps apps.)
Did you test the links above on your iOS test device? where dou you end up?

Comment: i tried opening the link at apple maps on a mac OS and it sends me to the atlantic ocean near affrica

Comment: Dude ty for your huge help just checked th sentence where you say you can get the wrong location with y=0;

Comment: I could get the other wrong location (near Africa) with x=0.

Comment: Ty so much i went to double...double... check and i was inputting coordinates as strings.

Comment: Parsed them to Doubles with a comma string in the middle and it worked like a charm.

Comment: build better your answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment that is why I am answering your question. I do not know why you are executing url to Device browser. I suggest better you use the "Map" control from Xamarin.Forms name space. I think it will full fill your requirement for set position on the exact point on the map.

[Here](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Xamarin-Forms-Maps-Sample) is the good sample of Xamarin.Forms.Map

**UPDATE-1**

I am not sure weather you want to use plugin or not. I found one good plug which can open external maps to a specific geolocation or address in your Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Windows, and Xamarin.Forms projects.

For more details and information please check [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/LaunchMapsPlugin).

Just found and tested code [here](https://sellsbrothers.com/13739) as well not sure if it is helpful to you. You might got the same earlier as well.

Comment: I'm not interested in making a Map view, I want to open default map app

Comment: the exact same thing happens. On android displays the location just fine, on iOS sends me into the sea.

Comment: Did you use this plug-in?

Comment: yes you can see the line of code in question update.